# Как правильно установить изображения в GridView? (Вопрос для дизайнеров мобильных приложений)

Tags: java, android, gridview

У меня тут такая проблема,

я хочу нарисовать буквы алфавита в разных цветах и поместить их в GridView.

1)Как правильно подобрать размер изображения? потому, что если картинка большая и качественная то приложение просто вылетает, так как при скролинге не может устанавливать большие картинки в грид. Если я делаю руками ее меньше, то она получается маленькая и теряется качество и приходится регулировать размер. Это очень не удобно!

2)Я думаю может есть, какое то решение, чтоб как то программно их подгонять под нужный размер(Чтоб программно определялся наилучший размер картинки, так как на разных телефонах в зависимости от размера экрана они будут смотреться по разному - я так понимаю).

3)Есть ли какой то регламент - какой формат лучше использовать(svg, png, jpeg или прочие), какой максимальный вес картинки должен быть и прочее...

4)Я работаю на Ubuntu может есть какае-то программка для создания картинок удобная (в моем случае я рисую буквы вот такие)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пользуюсь Inkskape , но мне кажется это не совсем та программа которую нужно использовать в моем случае...

И может ли мне казаться что буквы смотрятся размытыми из за моего экрана? Но у меня в прицепи HTC Desire 500, вроде у него нормальный экран. Во всяком случае я пользуюсь другими приложениями и там изображения не смотрятся размытыми

Answer (score 2):

Очень много информации для одного вопроса. По каждому вопросу есть статьи и некоторые довольно объемные. Вкратце:

1.Дело опыта, но когда картинка попадает px на px в размер вашего контейнера, это идеальный вариант. К этому надо стремиться, возможностей для этого очень много.

2.Вы можете частично(или почти полностью) переложить обязанности отрисовки и рендеринга программно, но вы должны помнить, что вы задействуете дополнительные ресурсы системы. Вам решать. По моему мнению, использовать данных подход, необходимо если нет др. вариантов, те в крайний случай. Получается, что необходимо избегать этого и возможностей, также очень много.

3.Это тоже очень популярный вопрос в сети. Всё зависит от предпочтения, по опыту скажу. PNG > JPG. Причем в 90% случаев. Поэтому можете смело использовать этот графический формат.

SVG vs PNG. Здесь очень спорно, и как с jpg форматом, не подсказать. 
В умелых руках правильный svg, может сэкономить вам кучу места, но также наоборот, если вы сделали хорошую компрессию в png, здесь svg может сожрать прилично. Я использую оба формата, svg в основном для иконок и их анимаций, так как такой эффект на данный момент можно получить только с ним. 
Вот пример svg графики в android от меня [лампочка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SMqI04bVRE). Помимо этого идет небольшая, но иногда ощутимая экономия места.

4.Этот вопрос я считаю не по теме, программ очень много. Только Вам решать, какая для вас будет удобней. с svg я работаю в illustrator, остальное photoshop.

Если Вам кажется, что иконки размытые значит так и есть. Если вы видите на своем device изображения или иконки, которые выглядят лучше, значит вы можете сделать также и возможно ещё лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно в зависимости от разрешения и плотности экрана, подставлять подходящую для этих  параметров картинку?

Если да, то вам нужно заранее заготовить ресурсы картинок и разложить их по нужным папкам.

На пример, картинки для экрана с плотность `ldpi` - нужно положить в папку **res/drawable-ldpi** , картинку для экрана с плотность `hdpi` - нужно положить в папку **res/drawable-hdpi**. Разница между этими картинками в размере, базовой плотностью считается `mdpi` - потому для нее картинка должна быть 1:1 ,  а для всех  остальных плотностей, нужно ее умножить или поделить на нужный коэффициент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же, вам может быть полезным [туториал](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html) с офф.сайта

Comment: А может ли эту проблему решить формат svg? Я сейчас про него читаю и если я правильно понимаю, то это векторный формат который сам может принимать размеры области размещения без потери качества...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko в принципе да, правда по поводу рациональности использования того или иного формата в плане производительности ничего сказать не могу, надо тестить. Возможно вам будет интересен вариант с использованием 9.png , это такой формат в котором можно указать параметры масштабирования изображения, вот статья на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/post/113623/